# Inflate mapview second time throws exception

Tags: android, android-mapview, inflate

I have a simple Android activity that should present some status both on a mapview and in textual form.

I have done this as two layouts that i swap between with setContentView(). At start it works fine, display the map. I can then swap to the textstatus view by pressing menu button and selecting Text view. But when I want to swap back to map the setContentView(R.layout.main); (that layout holds only a MapView and a linear layout) throws the following exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7:
   Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Anyone got any ideas? I am quite new to Android development so I dont know for sure that this is the best way to solve the problem.

**Source listing:**

maptest.java:

```
public class maptest extends MapActivity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

 mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(65.319416667*1000000),
          (int)(18.073833333*1000000)));

 mapController.setZoom(8);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
 return true;
  }    

  //@Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.map_view:
     try{
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error");
      System.out.println(e.toString());
     }

     return true;

    case R.id.text_view:
     setContentView(R.layout.statustext);
     return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }

}
```

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
```

statustext.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Status text"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.csr.maptest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
```

```
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".maptest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

```
</manifest>
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/text_view"
      android:title="Text view" />           
  <item android:id="@+id/map_view"
      android:title="Map view" />
</menu>
```

Comment: did you figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss something in the Main.xml? I can't see the

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView ... />
```

and you didn't close the LinearLayout.

However, the problem is that you are only allowed to instantiate a single MapView in a MapActivity.
I think, that everytime you do

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

your mapview will be inflated and MapView is instantiated.
So, you may better create the MapView in Code and take care, that you instantiate it only once:

```
if (mapView == null)
  mapView = new MapView(this, "your-api-key");
```

and

```
findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01).addView(mapView);
```